# Recyclerview shows wrong data

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

output shows only last item of list 
i.e, 
16:15-16:30 
16:15-16:30
where as it should show
16:00-16:15 
16:15-16:30

json output

```
 {
    "slots": [{
        "1": {
            "slot": "16:00-16:15",
            "value": "1",
            "ar_index": "1"
        },
        "2": {
            "slot": "16:15-16:30",
            "value": "2",
            "ar_index": "2"
        }
    }]
 }
```

Here is the postexecute code that im using to fetch json output and setting it in recyclerview using adapter
Im fetching these two slots and displaying in recyclerview but im geting only the last time of the list. not able to understand the issue with the code

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            //this method will be running on UI thread

            pdLoading.dismiss();
            List<DataBook> data=new ArrayList<>();

            pdLoading.dismiss();
            try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                    System.out.println("jsonObject_1 = "+jsonObject);

                    if(jsonObject != null){
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("slots");
                        System.out.println("jsonArray_2 = "+jsonArray);

                        if(jsonArray != null) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                System.out.println("jsonArray.length() = "+jsonArray.length());
                                System.out.println("i_value = "+i);

                                JSONObject elem = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                System.out.println("elem = " + elem);

                                for (int j = 1; j <= elem.length(); j++) {
                                    System.out.println("elem.length() = "+elem.length());
                                    System.out.println("j_value = "+j);

                                    JSONObject elem1 = elem.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(j));
                                    System.out.println("elem1 = " + elem1);
                                    DataBook fishData = new DataBook();

                                    if (elem1 != null) {
                                        fishData.fishName = elem1.getString("slot");
                                        System.out.println("fishData.fishName = " + fishData.fishName);
                                    }
                                    data.add(fishData);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
// Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
                mRVFishPrice = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rc_slotsList);
                mAdapter = new AdapterFish(BookActivity.this, data);
                mRVFishPrice.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mRVFishPrice.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(BookActivity.this));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(BookActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

This is my Adapter class were i am setting the result

```
public class AdapterFish extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<DataBook> data= Collections.emptyList();
    DataBook current;
    int currentPos=0;

    // create constructor to innitilize context and data sent from MainActivity
    public AdapterFish(Context context, List<DataBook> data){
        this.context=context;
        inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;
    }

    // Inflate the layout when viewholder created
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.book_container_fish, parent,false);
        MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    // Bind data
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        // Get current position of item in recyclerview to bind data and assign values from list
        MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
        current = data.get(position);

        myHolder.textFishName.setText(current.fishName);
        System.out.println("holder_current.fishName"+current.fishName);

    }

    // return total item from List
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView textFishName;
        ImageView ivFish;
        TextView textSize;
        TextView textType;
        TextView textPrice;

        // create constructor to get widget reference
        public MyHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textFishName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textFishName);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: int position gives you the value 1 hence you have to start position -1;

Comment: on adding position-1 app got crashed giving error
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1

Comment: public AdapterFish(Context context, List<DataBook> data){
        this.context=context;
        inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;
    }  Print you all data that you have got from calss using for then you will come whers the problem

Comment: holder_current.fishName = 16:15-16:30
holder_current.fishName = 16:15-16:30

in adapter while setting its taking same value for both the item

Comment: Different value for both the item
fishData.fishName = 16:00-16:15
 fishData.fishName = 16:15-16:30

Comment: Hi thanks for all the help.. found the solution. i had declared string variable as public static String fishName;.... thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
public AdapterFish(Context context, List<DataBook> data){
        this.context=context;
        inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;
      system.out.println(""+data.size());
//check how much data that you have got


    } 
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        // Get current position of item in recyclerview to bind data and 
        assign values from list
        MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
        current = data.get(position-1);

        myHolder.textFishName.setText(current.fishName);
        System.out.println("holder_current.fishName"+current.fishName);

    }
```

Comment: on adding position-1 app got crashed giving error
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1